# how to write in edit text using custom keyboard application in android

Tags: android

i am doing an application that needs a special keyboard and i can get the text into a edit text by pressing the keys.

public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements
        OnKeyboardActionListener, OnKeyListener {

```
private static final String TAG = SecondActivity.class.getName();
private EditText editText1, editText2, editText3;
private InputMethodManager imm;
private String mWordSeparators;
private StringBuilder mComposing = new StringBuilder();
private KeyboardView keyboardView;
private Keyboard keyboard;
private Keyboard miKeyboard;
private boolean mCapsLock;
private long mLastShiftTime;
private boolean mCompletionOn;
private long mMetaState;
private CompletionInfo[] mCompletions;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Log.d("cambio estado", "onDestroy");
        }
    });

    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            Log.d("cambio estado", "onDestroy");
        }
    });

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText1.getWindowToken(), 0);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText2.getWindowToken(), 0);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText3.getWindowToken(), 0);
    mWordSeparators = getResources().getString(R.string.word_separators);

    keyboardView = (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    miKeyboard = new Keyboard(this,R.xml.qwerty);
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    keyboardView.setEnabled(true);
    keyboardView.setPreviewEnabled(true);
    keyboardView.setOnKeyListener(this);
    keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
}

public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {

    mComposing.setLength(0);
    updateCandidates();

    if (!restarting) {
        mMetaState = 0;
    }

    mCompletionOn = false;
    mCompletions = null;

    switch (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME:
            keyboard = miKeyboard;
            break;

        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE:
            keyboard = miKeyboard;
            break;

        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
            keyboard = miKeyboard;
            updateShiftKeyState(attribute);
            break;

        default:
            keyboard = miKeyboard;
            updateShiftKeyState(attribute);
    }
    }

 public void onDisplayCompletions(CompletionInfo[] completions) {
    if (mCompletionOn) {
        if (completions == null) {
            return;
        }
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < completions.length; i++) {
            CompletionInfo ci = completions[i];
            if (ci != null) stringList.add(ci.getText().toString());
        }
    }
}

 private boolean translateKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     mMetaState = MetaKeyKeyListener.handleKeyDown(mMetaState,
             keyCode, event);
     int c = event.getUnicodeChar(MetaKeyKeyListener.getMetaState(mMetaState));
     mMetaState = MetaKeyKeyListener.adjustMetaAfterKeypress(mMetaState);
     InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
     if (c == 0 || ic == null) {
         return false;
     }
     if ((c & KeyCharacterMap.COMBINING_ACCENT) != 0) {
         c = c & KeyCharacterMap.COMBINING_ACCENT_MASK;
     }  
     if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
         char accent = mComposing.charAt(mComposing.length() -1 );
         int composed = KeyEvent.getDeadChar(accent, c);
         if (composed != 0) {
             c = composed;
             mComposing.setLength(mComposing.length()-1);
         }
     } 
     onKey(c, null);
     return true;
 }

 private void hideDefaultKeyboard() {
      getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
     }

private void handleShift() {
    checkToggleCapsLock();
    keyboardView.setShifted(mCapsLock || !keyboardView.isShifted());
}

private void checkToggleCapsLock() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (mLastShiftTime + 800 > now) {
        mCapsLock = !mCapsLock;
        mLastShiftTime = 0;
    } else {
        mLastShiftTime = now;
    }
}

private void updateCandidates() {
    if (!mCompletionOn) {
        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add(mComposing.toString());
        }
    }
}

private void handleClose() {
    commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());
    keyboardView.closing();
}

private void handleCharacter(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        if (keyboardView.isShifted()) {
            primaryCode = Character.toUpperCase(primaryCode);
        }
        else {
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
                String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 1);
    }
}

public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onText? \"" + text + "\"");
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    if (ic == null) return;
    ic.beginBatchEdit();
    if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
        commitTyped(ic);
    }
    ic.commitText(text, 0);
    ic.endBatchEdit();
    updateShiftKeyState((EditorInfo) getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
}

private void updateShiftKeyState(EditorInfo attr) {
    if (attr != null 
            && keyboardView != null && keyboard == keyboardView.getKeyboard()) {
        int caps = 0;
        EditorInfo ei = (EditorInfo) getCurrentInputEditorInfo();
        if (ei != null && ei.inputType != InputType.TYPE_NULL) {
            caps = getCurrentInputConnection().getCursorCapsMode(attr.inputType);
        }
        keyboardView.setShifted(mCapsLock || caps != 0);
    }}

private void commitTyped(InputConnection inputConnection) {
    if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
        inputConnection.commitText(mComposing, mComposing.length());
        mComposing.setLength(0);
        updateCandidates();
    }
}

private String getWordSeparators() {
    return mWordSeparators;
}

public boolean isWordSeparator(int code) {
    String separators = getWordSeparators();
    return separators.contains(String.valueOf((char)code));
}

private void handleBackspace() {
    final int length = mComposing.length();
    if (length > 1) {
        mComposing.delete(length - 1, length);
        getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposing, 1);
        updateCandidates();
    } else if (length > 0) {
        mComposing.setLength(0);
        getCurrentInputConnection().commitText("", 0);
        updateCandidates();
    } else {
        keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
    }
    updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
}


private InputConnection getCurrentInputConnection() {
    return getCurrentInputConnection();
}

private EditorInfo getCurrentInputEditorInfo() {
    return getCurrentInputEditorInfo();
}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {
    Log.d(TAG, "swipeUp");
}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
    Log.d(TAG, "swipeRight");
}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {
    Log.d(TAG, "swipeLeft");
    handleBackspace();
}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {
    Log.d(TAG, "swipeDown");
    handleClose();
}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRelease? primaryCode=" + primaryCode);
}

@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onPress? primaryCode=" + primaryCode);
}

@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onKey? primaryCode=" + primaryCode);
    int n1 = 0; // -1 count
    for (int keyCode : keyCodes) {
        if (keyCode == -1) {
            n1++;
            continue;
        }
        Log.v(TAG, "keyCode=" + keyCode);
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "keyCode=-1 *" + n1);
if (isWordSeparator(primaryCode)) {
    if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
        commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());
    }
    sendKey(primaryCode);
    updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
} else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE) {
    handleBackspace();
} else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT) {
    handleShift();
} else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL) {
    handleClose();
} else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE
        && keyboardView != null) {
    Keyboard current = keyboardView.getKeyboard();
    keyboardView.setKeyboard(current);
} else {
    handleCharacter(primaryCode, keyCodes);
}
```

}

```
private void sendKey(int keyCode) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case '\n':
            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
            break;
        default:
            if (keyCode >= '0' && keyCode <= '9') {
                keyDownUp(keyCode - '0' + KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0);
            } else {
                getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(String.valueOf((char) keyCode), 1);
            }
            break;
    }
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
            if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && keyboardView != null) {
                if (keyboardView.handleBack()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            break;    
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL:
            if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
                onKey(Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE, null);
                return true;
            }
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            return false;
        default:
            if (mCapsLock) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE
                        && (event.getMetaState()&KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON) != 0) {
                    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
                    if (ic != null) {
                        ic.clearMetaKeyStates(KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON);
                        keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
                        keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_N);
                        keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D);
                        keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_R);
                        keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O);
                        keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I);
                        keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                if (translateKeyDown(keyCode, event)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void keyDownUp(int keyEventCode) {
    getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
            new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyEventCode));
    getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
            new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyEventCode));
}

@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    hideDefaultKeyboard();
    Log.d(TAG, "onKey? keyCode=" + keyCode);
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your Xml file, Inside the editText tag you find something like `android:inputType` attribute. you can specify different types of input types like textEmail, phoneNumber, textPassword.

There are so many types, if you specify the input type attribute, it will show custom keyboard according to input type,

`If your editText input type is a phoneNumber, then it will show Num KeyPad`

`If your editText input type is a textPassword, then it will show Character Keypad`

Like this, you can have more custom keypad / keyboard

For Password keypad,

```
     <EditText android:id=..........
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
```

For Numeric Keypad

```
     <EditText android:id=..........
            android:inputType="number" />
```

Comment: i have tried this but doesn't work i thing is something wrong with the input connection , getCurentInputConnection  but i don't know how to fix this, any idea?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you declared it in manifest like

```
  <service
            android:name="TamilSoftKeyboard"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.view.im"
                android:resource="@xml/method" />
        </service>
```